# Android JAX-WS application

Tags: android, web-services, jax-ws

I am creating an android web service as given in this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/ but as I execute my app I get this in my logcat.

```
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at com.example.androidwsclient.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
06-18 15:11:23.980: E/AndroidRuntime(26893):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help?? Please I am so new to this. I am creating an android application that uses JAX-WS to display data. also in my source code:

```
private static String URL="http://my ipconfig:3333/HelloWebService/HelloWSService?WSDL"; 
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "hello";
```

i found my ip from cmd. please is this correct too???

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the ksoap2 library. You can download it at: http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/